# SQL wringing a JOIN

Tags: sql

so I have 2 tables

Table 1: Languages

```
| language_id | language |
-------------------------
|     1      |    java  |
|     2      |      c   |
```

Table 2: People

```
| person_id  | person_name | expert_lang | years_experience |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|     1      | Neil        |       1     |        15        |
|     2      | John        |       1     |        10        |
|     3      | Lucy        |       2     |        12        |
```

Now what i'm trying to do is find the total years of experience for each language so it would produce a table like follows:

```
| language | total_years_experience |
-------------------------------------
| java     |          25            |
| c        |          12            |
```

I cant seem to get anything to work, could anyone help? would be much appreciated!

Comment: This seems to be a very simple join operation. It is good to write the query on own and it is the only way to learn the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try joining the tables

```
SELECT language, SUM(years_experience) as total_years_experience FROM languages
INNER JOIN people ON languages.language_id=people.expert_lang 
GROUP BY expert_lang
```

Comment: In most dialects of SQL, your query would not parse because `language` is not included in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Thanks for this! It was the group by part i was missing

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT  l.languna ,SUM(p.years_experience) 
FROM Languages  l INNER JOIN People  p ON l.lagu_id=p.expert_lang
GROUP BY l.languna
```

Answer (score 0):

Rapli's answer is basically correct.  However, I think an outer join may be important in case some languages have no users with matching experience:

```
SELECT l.language, coalesce(SUM(p.years_experience), 0) as total_years_experience
FROM languages l LEFT OUTER JOIN
     people p
     ON l.language_id = p.expert_lang 
GROUP BY l.language
order by total_years_experience desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to JOIN the tables together on language_id and expert_lang, and then SUM the years_experience column for each language.

```
SELECT l.language, SUM(years_experience) as total_years_experience
FROM #Languages l
JOIN #People p ON l.language_id = p.expert_lang
GROUP BY l.language
```